# Can't solve this integral. Solution involves hypergeometric functions.

Tags: integration, hypergeometric-function

I need to re-derive a result from a paper:
$$
\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}\,{\rm d}x\, \left\vert x\right\vert\,x^{n}\,
\Theta\left(\frac{x}{c}\right)
\exp\left(%
-\,\frac{1}{2}\left\{abc + \frac{\left[bc\right]^{2} + 1}{\beta bc}x \right\}^{2}\,%
\right)
\tag{1}
$$
where $\Theta$ is the step function, $n \in \mathbb{N^+}$ , $a,c \in \mathbb{R} $ , $\beta \in [1,2]$ and $b \in [0,\infty)$.

It says the solution is:

$$
2^{n/2} {\Big(\frac{\beta bc}{{(bc)}^2+1}\Big)}^{n}e^{-\frac{{(abc)}^2}{2}} \Big[ \Gamma(1+\frac{n}{2})M(1+\frac{n}{2},\frac{1}{2};\frac{{(abc)}^2}{2}) + \sqrt{2}\:abc\:\Gamma(\frac{3+n}{2})M(\frac{3+n}{2},\frac{3}{2};\frac{{(abc)}^2}{2}) \Big]
\tag{2}
$$
Where $M$ is the [Kummer's confluent hypergeometric function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confluent_hypergeometric_function).

I think it can be useful the relation with the Tricomi funcion that you can find in the same wikipedia page:

$$
U(\alpha,\gamma;z)=\frac{1}{\Gamma(\alpha)} \int^{\infty}_{0} dt \: e^{-zt} t^{\alpha-1} {(1+t)}^{\gamma-\alpha-1} \tag{3}
$$
$$
U(\alpha,\gamma;z)=\frac{\Gamma(1-\gamma)}{\Gamma(\alpha-\gamma+1)}M(\alpha,\gamma;z) + \frac{\Gamma(\gamma-1)}{\Gamma(\alpha)}z^{1-\gamma}M(\alpha-\gamma+1,2-\gamma;z) 
\tag{4}
$$

if we put:
$$
\alpha=1+\frac{n}{2} \\
\gamma=\frac{1}{2} \\
z=\frac{{(abc)}^2}{2}
\tag{5}
$$
(4) resembles the result that I have to prove. It seems that i have to manipulate the original integral into something like the U integral form (3).

I'm sorry for the cumbersome parameters but I want to preserve the original form of the problem.

**UPDATE:**
I verified numerically that must be an error in (2), there is a minus between the two $M$ functions:
$$
2^{n/2} {\Big(\frac{\beta bc}{{(bc)}^2+1}\Big)}^{n}e^{-\frac{{(abc)}^2}{2}} \Big[ \Gamma(1+\frac{n}{2})M(1+\frac{n}{2},\frac{1}{2};\frac{{(abc)}^2}{2}) - \sqrt{2}\:abc\:\Gamma(\frac{3+n}{2})M(\frac{3+n}{2},\frac{3}{2};\frac{{(abc)}^2}{2}) \Big]
\tag{6}
$$

**UPDATE 2:**
I posted a simplified version of the question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/555824/prove-that-int-x-an1-e-x2-2-2n-2exp-a2-2-big-gamma1n-2),
I really hope this is not a problem with double identical questions!

Thank you for your patience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved thanks to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/99418/how-to-evaluate-a-definite-integral-looks-almost-like-nonintegral-moments-of-a).
It is the same integral with the obvious substitution
$$
y= \frac{{(bc)}^2+1}{\beta bc}x
$$